# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using Python to start Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I need help getting Jupyter Lab started. I was able to open and work in it just fine until recently. Now, whenever I try to run `jupyter-lab` from Command Prompt in Windows 10, I get the following error message:

```
    Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\[MyUser]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\jupyter-lab.exe" '
```

The issue seems to have started after I created an alias called `python` to run Python 3 instead of Python 2.

For additional context, python.exe is in my Python38 folder, not Python38-32.

Comment: How did you define the alias?

Comment: In the Command Prompt, I think I simply did `alias python=python3`.

Comment: Did you check your `PATH`? (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) for info on how).

Comment: I've been messing around in the Environment Variables, but nothing seems to work. On my computer `python.exe` is located under `C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`, so I've added that under Path and PYTHONPATH in the User Variables and System Variables sections. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I simply needed to reboot my computer after adding my path variables, a simple tip I found [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/). SMH